# Are the powers listed only in the Red Box available to use or deliberately removed?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

I don't see Poised Strike and Stone Blood in any books other than the 4e Red Box.  I believe there are quite a few others (listed below). Why weren't these added into the 4e PHB or other 'essentials' books? Can we continue to use these powers beyond the Red Box quests, or are they too powerful or deliberately removed for some other reason?

Other Red Box 'unique' powers:

- Rogue powers
- Leaden transmutation
- Slimy transmutation
- Battle fury
- Echoes of thunder
- Human versatility
- Phantasmal force

Comment: Slimy/Leaden Transmutation & Stone Blood are apparently the only powers from the Red Box that made it into the Compendium. *Why* the others weren't reprinted or added to the compendium is arguably beyond the scope of this site, as it basically rests on reading the dev's minds and thus excludes answers based on fact or personal experience.

Comment: @ObliviousSage That's only true if they haven't made any public statements --  there are many types of questions where, unfortunately, the answer is "we can't know."

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's just marketing to get people to pick up Red Box as well as the PH's.

Comment: Some of the Red Box powers were later renamed or errata'd, I believe. There were some instances where what was printed did not match what we found in the compendium and other updated sources. I would suggest checking the Character Builder for the powers you're after - it's possible it's just a name change.

Answer (score 3):

**Most of the powers were either renamed or reworked into other powers.** They haven't all been "removed" exactly, but I don't think you can use them outside of the Red Box environment to create characters.

Here is what I could find based off your list:

- **Rogue Powers**: Most of these appear to have been reworked as the "Trick" powers you can use as the Rogue (Thief) class, but `Deft Strike` and `Tumble` are still available
- **Leaden Transmutation** - Now `Leaden Transformation`
- **Slimy Transmutation** - In the Compendium
- **Battle Fury** - Now `Battle Wrath` but only applies to basic attacks
- **Echoes of Thunder** - Now `Thundering Steel` (There's also an unrelated feat with the original name)
- **Human Versatility** - See `Heroic Effort` - No longer applies to skill or ability checks
- **Phantasmal Force** - In the Compendium as `Phantasmal Assault`, gained the `Psychic` keyword

When in doubt, I would say stick with what's in the Compendium (or, failing that, the Essentials Heroes books). From what I can tell, the Red Box and all those cards were printed before a lot of the abilities were finalized. If you're running a full 4E/Essentials game you should probably try to use the updated powers, but if you're just using the Red Box I'm sure you'll be fine.

Then again, you can always house rule whatever you feel like.

Answer (score 2):

You should be OK to use them elsewhere. It's not unusual for material to only be printed in *one* book - WotC is trying to produce new material for each book, since that's why players buy them! Reprinting old material would be a waste of pages unless there's a strong reason for it to be there.

The Compendium doesn't appear to list a lot of them (like @ObliviousSage mentioned), but it appears it listed almost *nothing* from that book.