# Is there an fire version of Wintertouched in D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

I found the Wintertouched feat in D&D 4e, which grants you combat advantage against foes that are weak to cold. I'm wondering though, is there a version that gives you combat advantage if a foe is weak against fire?

Comment: Wintertouched is a UNIQUE and powerful feat. It's one of the main reasons cold damage is so popular in 4e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wintertouched's exact phrasing is this:

> When attacking a creature that is vulnerable to cold, you gain combat advantage when you use a power that has the cold keyword.

I searched [the Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx)'s feats list for "combat advantage fire", and "vulnerable fire". There were only three results for each and they weren't Fire versions of Wintertouched.

Since a Fire version isn't in the Compendium, which is a comprehensive database of almost* everything rules-wise in D&D, it *probably* doesn't exist.

You could make one up, though!

<sup>* To my knowledge the only thing they didn't document thoroughly was [the Red Box player's book](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26217/1204). It's safe to assume it contains basically everything else.</sup>